# Numba "Use of unsupported opcode (CONTINUE_LOOP) found" error when using continue in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, numba

I am getting an error trying to enable numba optimization on a defined function.

Here is the function simplified:

```
@jit
def monte_carlo(iterations):
    key1 = []
    key2 = []
    score = []
    for i in range(iterations):
        random.seed(i)
        temp_matrix = random.sample(matrix, length)

        for j in range(iterations):
            random.seed(j)
            key2.append(i)
            key1.append(j)

            for x in range(...):
                try: temp_matrix[x] = random.sample(matrix[x], len(matrix[x]))
                except: continue


        scores.append(...)
    return scores, keyA, keyB

monte_carlo(1000)
```

Then I receive this as an error, also had issues using Cuda over Jit.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..."
  File ...\numba\dispatcher.py", line 404, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')
  File "...\numba\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "...\numba\six.py", line 668, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.UnsupportedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
**Use of unsupported opcode (CONTINUE_LOOP) found**

File "...py", line 32:
def monte_carlo(iterations):
    <source elided>
                try: temp_qa_matrix[x] = random.sample(input.qa_matrix[x], len(input.qa_matrix[x]))
                except: continue
                ^
```

So, it is not really liking the continue in a loop, despite being a supported construct.

[Nunba Supported Python features](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html?highlight=continue)

Answer (score 5):

I think Numba's documentation is a little incomplete. It can handle ordinary `continue` statements, which use the Python opcode `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` under the hood, but not `continue` statements inside try/except blocks, which use the Python opcode `CONTINUE_LOOP`.

Here's an example of a simple function that (unnecessarily) uses `continue` and works with Numba. It cuts in half elements of an array that are greater than 0.5.

```
def halve(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] <= 0.5:
            continue
        x[i] /= 2
```

If we import the Python `dis` module and look at the output of `dis.dis(halve)`, we see that there are two `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` opcodes. This is what Python normally uses for `continue` statements. If we use Numba jit this function and run it an array, we'll see that it works with no problem.

But if we rewrite `halve` to use try/except:

```
def halve(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        try:
            assert x[i] > 0.5
        except:
            continue
        x[i] /= 2
```

and look at `dis.dis(halve)`, we see that one of the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` opcodes has been replaced by `CONTINUE_LOOP`. I don't know the Python details under the hood, but sure enough, if we try to jit this function, then Numba complains that there's an unsupported opcode.

So, TLDR: looks like you can't use continue inside try/except with Numba, for obscure reasons related to the Python implementation.

I suspect there's almost always a workaround to this, but since your code isn't fully self-contained it's hard for me to know.

(Side note: usually Numba will do much better if you use NumPy arrays rather than lists.)

Comment: "I suspect there's almost always a workaround to this, but since your code isn't fully self-contained it's hard for me to know." If the logic actually is exactly as shown, it seems like the `except:continue` could just be `except:pass`? Since there's nothing else inside that loop?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly true!

Comment: I actually did that previously and got thrown another issue which is an resolved bug. Will update if I ever fix it